# How do I display the checkbox value on the update form Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm creating a form to be inputted into the database, but on the update form I can't display the `checkbox` value. This is hindering my coursework, I hope someone can helps

**add_view.php :**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label><b> Minat : </b></label> <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="minat[]" value="Programming"> Programming <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="minat[]" value="Desain Grafis">  Desain Grafis <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="minat[]" value="Animasi">  Animasi <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="minat[]" value="Fotografi">  Fotografi <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="minat[]" value="Videografi">  Videografi </div> <br>
```

**controller :**

```
function save(){
    $nodaftar = $this->input->post('nodaftar');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $kelamin = $this->input->post('kelamin');
    $minat = $this->input->post('minat');
    $minat = implode(",", $minat);
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $tmpt_lahir = $this->input->post('tmpt_lahir');
    $tgl_lahir =  $this->input->post('tgl_lahir');
    $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $kritik = $this->input->post('kritik');
    $this->daftar_model->save($nodaftar,$nama,$kelamin,$minat,$email,$tmpt_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$alamat,$kritik);
    redirect('daftar');
}

function get_edit(){
    $no = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result = $this->daftar_model->get_daftar_id($no);
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        $i = $result->row_array();
        $data = array(
            'no' => $i['no'],
            'nodaftar' => $i['nodaftar'],
            'nama' => $i['nama'],
            'kelamin' => $i['kelamin'],
            'minat' => $i['minat'],
            'email' => $i['email'],
            'tmpt_lahir' => $i['tmpt_lahir'],
            'tgl_lahir' => $i['tgl_lahir'],
            'alamat' => $i['alamat'],
            'kritik' => $i['kritik'],
    );
    $this->load->view('edit_daftar_view',$data);
}else{
    echo "Data Was Not Found";
    }
}

function update(){
    $no = $this->input->post('no');
    $nodaftar = $this->input->post('nodaftar');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $kelamin = $this->input->post('kelamin');
    $minat = $this->input->post('minat');
    $minat = implode(",", $minat);
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $tmpt_lahir = $this->input->post('tmpt_lahir');
    $tgl_lahir = $this->input->post('tgl_lahir');
    $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $kritik = $this->input->post('kritik');
    $this->daftar_model->update($no,$nodaftar,$nama,$kelamin,$minat,$email,$tmpt_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$alamat,$kritik);
    redirect('daftar');
}
}
```

**models :**

```
function save($nodaftar,$nama,$kelamin,$minat,$email,$tmpt_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$alamat,$kritik){
    $data = array(
        'nodaftar' => $nodaftar,
        'nama' => $nama,
        'kelamin' => $kelamin,
        'minat' => $minat,
        'email' => $email, 
        'tmpt_lahir' => $tmpt_lahir,
        'tgl_lahir' => $tgl_lahir,
        'alamat' => $alamat,
        'kritik' => $kritik,
    );
    $this->db->insert('anggota1',$data);
}

function get_daftar_id($no){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('anggota1', array('no' => $no)); 
    return $query;
}

function update($no,$nodaftar,$nama,$kelamin,$minat,$email,$tmpt_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$alamat,$kritik){
    $data = array(
        'nodaftar' => $nodaftar,
        'nama' => $nama,
        'kelamin' => $kelamin,
        'minat' => $minat,
        'email' => $email, 
        'tmpt_lahir' => $tmpt_lahir,
        'tgl_lahir' => $tgl_lahir,
        'alamat' => $alamat,
        'kritik' => $kritik
    );
    $this->db->where('no', $no);
    $this->db->update('anggota1', $data);
}
}
```

**edit_view.php :**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b> Minat : </b></label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="minat[]" value="Programming" <?php if ($minat == 'Programming') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Programming
             <input type="checkbox" name="minat[]" value="Desain Grafis" <?php if ($minat == 'Desain Grafis') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Desain Grafis
             <input type="checkbox" name="minat[]" value="Animasi" <?php if ($minat == 'Animasi') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Animasi 
             <input type="checkbox" name="minat[]" value="Fotografi" <?php if ($minat == 'Fotografi') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Fotografi 
             <input type="checkbox" name="minat[]" value="Videografi" <?php if ($minat == 'Videografi') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Videografi <br> <br>
```

Comment: you do `$minat = implode(",", $minat);` while update, so during populating your edit form why don't you do `$minat = explode(",", $minat);` ? and then `if(in_array('Programming',$minat)) echo 'checked="checked"'`